# Has the 3.5e Samurai been rebuilt for Pathfinder?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class, conversion

I read the Pathfinder *Ultimate Equipment Guide* and noticed that the Katana and Wakizashi got their own weapon count (as well as a samurai armor as an armor type). Has someone converted the samurai class from Oriental adventures and Complete Warrior from 3.5 for Pathfinder?

Comment: Is there something wrong with the existing [Pathfinder Samurai](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/alternate-classes/samurai)?

Comment: Do answers to this question go beyond "Yes, I have tried to recreate and fix the samurai class"? What are you actually asking here?

Comment: (I'm assuming you're asking if someone "out there in the Internet" has already done a fan conversion. I did an edit along those lines, since otherwise this is an easy close vote for being a poll. If that's not what you intended to ask about, some clarification would be appreciate!)

Comment: Also note the OA and CW samurais are significantly different - which one are you interested in?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie turn that into an easy answer. "Yes, here's the link. Here's what they changed.

Comment: @BrianBallsun-Stanton Good idea. I would, but I must leave that to someone who knows that material better. (So: anyone want to "steal" that answer, go for it!)

Comment: Answer wasn't quite that easy, due to the Pathfinder Samurai not actually descending from the CW and OA versions in any way. If anything, it descends more from the Knight and mounted (generally Fighter and Ranger) builds.

Comment: @CataruMoore We may have mentioned http://www.d20pfsrd.com/ before - it has all official PF rules content and some third party - you might go check there for "does X exist."

Answer (score 6):

### Sort Of

The [Pathfinder Samurai](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/alternate-classes/samurai) relates to the Oriental Adventures and Complete Warrior Samurai in name only—mechanically, it has much more in common with the Knight (PHB II), Paladin, and even the Ranger than the Samurai from either D&D book. As can be seen in the link above, it is a variation on Pathfinder's Cavalier. That being said, the OA Samurai is not easily distinguishable from a Fighter in either edition; its only unique capability, the Ancestral Daisho, is effectively duplicated by [Master Craftsman](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/master-craftsman---final) along with [Craft Magic Arms and Armor](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/item-creation-feats/craft-magic-arms-and-armor-item-creation---final).

The Complete Warrior Samurai grants 5 specific feats (all of which are on the Fighter feat list), a Smite Evil-like effect (damage bonus), and several bonuses and modifications to intimidate. Again, these effects are all duplicable or near-duplicable with feats and Fighter class features.

In conclusion, Pathfinder ported the functionality of the Samurai (both of them), and has a class called Samurai, but the class called Samurai has next to no overlap with the Samurai of D&D 3.0 and 3.5.

Comment: The pathfinder Samurai is an alternate class for the Cavalier base class (just as the Ninja is based on the Rogue). It's essentially a reworded and somewhat reruled Cavalier.

Comment: Yeah. I made a judgement call and assumed that comparisons to 3.5 classes would be more helpful for people looking for ports of the OA and CW Samurai than discussing how Pathfinder's Samurai relates to the cavalier.